# How can I make the length of the spacing the same in x and y axis?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

[image: matplotlib showing unequal axis]

As one can see from the above picture, 1 unit on x-asis of the graph is different from that on y-axis (in terms of length). (So you see rectangle instead of square.)

I would like to ask how can I make it the same? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try using `plt.axis('equal')`. See [here](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/axis_equal_demo.html#pylab-examples-example-code-axis-equal-demo-py)

Comment: It works. Thanks!:) @MartinEvans

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can force matplotlib to use the same scaling for both axes by adding the following to your plot:

```
plt.axis('equal')
```

More information can be found here: [axis_equal_demo.py](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/axis_equal_demo.html)